# Disable right click in windows chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, autohotkey

I am trying to run chrome in kiosk mode and disable right clicking. I'm using a autohotkey script on startup and my current script is below:

```
#NoTrayIcon
RButton::Return
Run , C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -kiosk www.google.com
```

For some reason after compiling this script doesn't work. If I delete the second line then recompile then it works just fine. I'm using Windows 7 so did I enter this script command incorrectly? I don't know what else to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Run` command needs to be placed in the [Auto-execute Section](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) of the script, near the top and before hotkey definitions:

```
#singleInstance force  ; Replace old instance automatically
#noTrayIcon
run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=c:\temp www.google.com --kiosk  ; --incognito

#ifWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1  ; Only disable in Chrome

rButton::return  ; Disable right-click
; ^+esc::return  ; Disable Ctrl+Shift+Esc
; !f4::return  ; Disable Alt-F4
+!f4::  ; Shift-Alt-F4 to close kiosk/script
    winClose
    exitApp
```